# How to destroy a session of another than current user in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

I'm using asp.net 4.0 with asp.net MVC 2.0 and the asp.net membership provider.

I need to terminate a the user session before I delete it. Otherwise if the user is still authenticated the next time it will visit a page null reference exceptions will occur when trying to access the user data and profile.

I get the Session.Abandon() method but what I'm looking for is the same on a user, something like user.AbandonSessions().

I realize this question has been asked before but I can't get a straight answer.

Thanks

Comment: Im not sure I understand the question, maybe rephrase.  you can use Session.Abandon or even set the session variable to null when you are done using it.

Comment: The error is just an added "...and don't let the door hit you on the way out". No big deal IMO.

Comment: Pre - could you please clarify what you are trying to do. It is a bit ambiguous as is.

Comment: Greg, the session last 20 minutes. So if The account is destroyed you will be working on the application and will get fatal errors. I's not exactly a graceful outcome.

Code poet, my goal is to delete the user, and before I do that I want to terminate it's active session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be tilting at windmills. There are just too many things working against your desired goal.

If you adjust your perspective to embrace the arbitrary nature of a browser based app and instead of trying to eradicate all vestiges of a users state in order to avoid errors, rather take measures to ensure that the required data is present in the session and if not then recreate it or redirect the user to an appropriate location.

In any case, remember that in order to affect any session related action capably, you must force a request cycle to ensure the cookies are properly processed by the browser, but that is beside the point I am trying to make.

Good luck.

Comment: In the end my problem is that there are too many pieces of the application that do not validate before they access the session information. So you are correct the problem is not the outstanding session but the week validation of the session before it's accessed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom membership provider which instead of deleting an account, just deactivates that.  You could also have the custom membership provider to lock the account at the same time.

Comment: there is no mention of deleting a user. only ensuring discard of a session.

Comment: Actually, code poet, pre63 specifically says "...before I delete it.". Sounds like he's purely concerned with any errors the user might receive after visiting a page while authenticated, but after their account is gone.

Comment: @code poet: My interpretation of the question: deleting an ASP.NET membership user while that user is logged in from another browser.

Comment: @chris & Greg & all - yeah, upon reading it again, i can see how one might draw that conclusion. I think the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Chris, you are right. The goal is to destroy the session before deleting the user.

Answer (score 0):

FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

But you need to call it in the context of the user you want to sign out.

Comment: Sorry for replying to an old question, but how would I call this function in the context of another user?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.   I don't think you can.

Comment: it is not possible to call another user's SignOut... what you can do is maintain a list of session ids (as static variable) for users, and lookup in this list for each request....